# How to install ESS on Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, emacs, ess

I am trying to use Emacs instead of R on my Mac machine. I've been looking online how to install ESS so that I can use R in Emacs. But I am really confused by the installation manual which says,

Extract all the files from ess-VERSION.tgz into the directory PREFIX/site-lisp where
PREFIX is appropriate for GNU Emacs on your system; PREFIX will most likely be
either /usr/share/emacs or /usr/local/share/emacs (on Mac OS X, PREFIX will
most likely be something like /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources):

Where do I find this: /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources. I looked at Applications folder and it only contains the application file emacs.

Comment: I assume you are trying to move the files using finder? If so, CTRL+Click (right click) the "Emacs" application and select "Show package contents".

Answer (score 1):

Mac applications are bundled in folders with the .app extension. These folders are handled in a special manner by the finder which hides their contents. (See https://superuser.com/questions/78176/how-do-mac-app-execution-files-work for info). Specifically in you case `/Applications/Emacs.app` is really a folder. To get to its contents right click on it and choose "Show package contents". You will be able to get to `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources` from there.

Answer (score 0):

The ESS [documentation](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/readme.html#Installation) recommends using a [modified](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/) version of Emacs, which includes ESS and a few other packages. It is available for Windows and [Mac](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/mac/).